# How to write a logic based on count when concurrent requests are hitting in a webserver (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, redis, queue

In one of my requirements, a web application has to handle concurrent requests. In this application, I have to do some logic when count of list data reaches 50. Here I am using `redis/mogodb` for storing that list.

Each time a request comes I will push data to that list. Problem here is that since I have to handle concurrent requests, how can I limit the data to push on that list? If that limit is exceeded, I have to push data to another list.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What about locking? Every request are pushed in a queue, the first one gets the critical section when it enters. After the job is done CS is released and the count is increased. I don't know if concurrency is must in your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using lists in Redis, you can achieve this with a [Lua Script](https://redis.io/commands/eval). This way, the operation is atomic and you don't have to worry about concurrency.

In this example, you use key with a counter, simply to track the list currently being filled, then the script will evaluate the length of the current list, and if it will be full (with 50 entries in your case) after adding this entry, leave the counter pointing to the next list.

First, let's take a look at the Lua script:

```
local currentList = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1])
local listLen = redis.call('LLEN', 'list:'..currentList)
if listLen < (tonumber(ARGV[1]) - 1) then 
    return redis.call('LPUSH', 'list:'..currentList, ARGV[2])
else
    redis.call('INCR', KEYS[1])
    return redis.call('LPUSH', 'list:'..currentList, ARGV[2])
end
```

When using it, you pass the following arguments: `1 curList 50 <valueToPush>`, where `curList` is they key you are using for current list counter.

To avoid passing the full script every call, you can use `SCRIPT LOAD` and then `EVALSHA`.

The script returns the number of elements in the list where the new value has just been added. When it matches max-capacity, you can execute your additional logic.

Here an example of how to use it (pure Redis), using 3 instead of 50 for list max-capacity:

```
>> SET curList 1
OK
>> SCRIPT LOAD  "local currentList = redis.call('GET', KEYS[1]) \n local listLen = redis.call('LLEN', 'list:'..currentList) \n if listLen < (tonumber(ARGV[1]) - 1) then  \n return redis.call('LPUSH', 'list:'..currentList, ARGV[2]) \n else \n redis.call('INCR', KEYS[1]) \n return redis.call('LPUSH', 'list:'..currentList, ARGV[2]) \n end"
80f7e9a7ae0c32bdb0577861217ef680411c2941
>> EVALSHA 80f7e9a7ae0c32bdb0577861217ef680411c2941 1 curList 3 faa
1
>> EVALSHA 80f7e9a7ae0c32bdb0577861217ef680411c2941 1 curList 3 foo
2
>> EVALSHA 80f7e9a7ae0c32bdb0577861217ef680411c2941 1 curList 3 fuu
3
>> EVALSHA 80f7e9a7ae0c32bdb0577861217ef680411c2941 1 curList 3 fii
1
>> LRANGE list:1 0 -1
1) "fuu"
2) "foo"
3) "faa"
>> LRANGE list:2 0 -1
1) "fii"
```

There are many ways to implement this using Lua. The bottom line is for you to atomically perform the push, **you need to move the logic to the Redis server**, and the easiest way to achieve that is with a Lua script.

You can modify the return statements in the Lua script to `return 'list:'..currentList..' => '..redis.call('LPUSH', 'list:'..currentList, ARGV[2])`.  Then your return value gives you also the list where the item was added: `list:3 => 2`.

Comment: See https://thomashunter.name/posts/2017-07-14-redis-and-node-part-4-lua-scripting on how to use Redis Lua scripts in node